# urlManager rules with custom urls

Tags: php, yii

I want to be able to access/create some urls like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/player/Name-Surname-100/
```

In the view, my links are generated correctly using this:

```
$this->createUrl('player/view', array('id' => $player->id, 'slug' => $player->slug))
```

In my main.php configuration file I defined the following rule:

```
'player/<slug:\w+>-<id:\d+>' => 'ui/player/view',
```

but without success(I`m receiving the following error message: Unable to resolve the request "player/Name-Surname-100". ). In my "player" model (table) I also have the "slug" property(column).

Edit:

```
http://mywebsite.com/player/Name-Surname-anotherName-100/ //not working
http://mywebsite.com/player/Name_Surname_anotherName-100/ //it works!!
```

Comment: The correct rule is: 'player/<slug:[\w\-]+>-<id:\d+>' => 'ui/player/view'

Answer (score 0):

Your urlManager rule has the "-" as delimiter between the slug and the id.

Use the urlManager rule from Larry to allow "-" in the URL:

```
'player/<slug:[\w\-]+>-<id:\d+>' => 'ui/player/view'
```

---

Another way is to replace all "-" inside the slug.

```
$this->createUrl('player/view', array('id' => $player->id, 'slug' => str_replace('-','_'$player->slug));
```

Comment: I found the solution. The "-" between slug`s words is a "must be". Thanks anyway! :)